# /file.php to /file/ try out

Tags: php, redirect, slash

I wanted to redirect/rewrite my name.php files to /name/
I found the solution on another topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527789/htaccess-rewrite-within-directory-hide-php-extension-and-force-trailing-slash)

Though, I wanted to learn it myself and started from scratch.
I first used this one, which makes eg .com/test/ show the content of .com/test.php:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

Then I tried the following, by itself, which redirects .com/test.php to .com/test/:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://www.mydomain.info/$1/ [R=301]
```

So, both work on their own. But when I combine them, I get an loop error, even when I add [L] to it, which should mean the rules should only be used once. So this doesn't work:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://www.mydomain.info/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I've probably made some stupid error but it seems logically to me...
Hope someone can point out my error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an external redirect with the `R=301`, adding `L` to it doesn't help as much as you need, as the redirect will come back to the server as a brand new request - where it again matches your first rewrite rule.

Instead, you need something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\ /(.*)\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

Note that `THE_REQUEST` matches the entire line of the original request, e.g. `GET /index.php HTTP/1.1`.  Even when `%{REQUEST_URI}` is rewritten to `.php` as part of the 2nd rule (where it will match on an internal sub-request), `%{THE_REQUEST}` is never rewritten, and this will ensure that the URL rewritten to `.php` doesn't match on the sub-request and result in another redirect sent back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Remove L-flag from first rule. That would stop "executing" and the second rule wouldn't be used. At the second rule you should keep the L flag, because it is the last one.

Comment: Would have been great if this worked but I get the same results with or without it.

Comment: But you also let out that R=301?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't change. Thanks for trying to help though.